# malformed start tag error - Python, BeautifulSoup, and Sipie - Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just installed python, mplayer, beautifulsoup and sipie to run Sirius on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine.  I followed some docs that seem straightforward, but am encountering some issues.  I'm not that familiar with Python, so this may be out of my league.

I was able to get everything installed, but then running sipie gives this:

`/usr/bin/Sipie/Sipie/Config.py:12: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead import md5`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/Sipie/sipie.py", line 22, in <module>
    Sipie.cliPlayer()`
  `File "/usr/bin/Sipie/Sipie/cliPlayer.py", line 74, in cliPlayer
    completer = Completer(sipie.getStreams())`
  `File "/usr/bin/Sipie/Sipie/Factory.py", line 374, in getStreams
    streams = self.tryGetStreams()`
  `File "/usr/bin/Sipie/Sipie/Factory.py", line 298, in tryGetStreams
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)`
 `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1-py2.6.egg/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1499, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`
  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1-py2.6.egg/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)`
  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1-py2.6.egg/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1263, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(markup)`
 `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)`
  `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)`
  `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 226, in parse_starttag
    endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)`
  `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 301, in check_for_whole_start_tag
    self.error("malformed start tag")`
  `File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())`
`HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 100, column 3`

I looked through these files and the line numbers, but since I am unfamiliar with Python, it doesn't make much sense.  Any advice on what to do next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issues you are encountering are pretty common, and they deal specifically with mal-formed HTML. In my case, there was an HTML element which had double quoted an attribute's value. I ran into this issue today actually, and in so doing so came across your post. I was FINALLY able to resolve this issue through parsing the HTML through html5lib before handing it off the BeautifulSoup 4.

First off, you'll need to:

```
sudo easy_install bs4
sudo apt-get install python-html5lib
```

Then, run this example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
from html5lib import sanitizer
from html5lib import treebuilders
import urllib

url = 'http://the-url-to-scrape'
fp = urllib.urlopen(url)

# Create an html5lib parser. Not sure if the sanitizer is required.
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("beautifulsoup"), tokenizer=sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer)
# Load the source file's HTML into html5lib
html5lib_object = parser.parse(file_pointer)
# In theory we shouldn't need to convert this to a string before passing to BS. Didn't work passing directly to BS for me however.
html_string = str(html5lib_object)

# Load the string into BeautifulSoup for parsing.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)

for content in soup.findAll('div'):
    print content
```

If you have any questions about this code or need a little more specific guidance, just let me know. :)

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Unrecognised treebuilder "beautifulsoup"`

(Python 2.7.5, beautifulsoup 4.3.2, html5lib 0.999)

Answer (score 15):

Suppose you are using BeautifulSoup4, I found out something in the official document about this: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

> If you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version
>   of Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install lxml
>   or html5lib–Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in
>   older versions.

I tried this and it works well, just like what @Joshua

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: Is this "r" in the above code an html object from the requests library? No matter the case, this great oneliner works like a charm using the pycurl library,too. +1

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of BeautifulSoup [uses HTMLParser rather than SGMLParser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) (due to SGMLParser being removed from the Python 3.0 standard library). As a result, BeautifulSoup can no longer process many malformed HTML documents correctly, which is what I believe you are encountering here.

A solution to your problem is likely to be to [uninstall BeautifulSoup, and install an older version](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2009/09/26/python-downgrading-beatifulsoup.html) (which will still work with Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.04LTS):

```
sudo apt-get remove python-beautifulsoup
sudo easy_install -U "BeautifulSoup==3.0.7a"
```

Just be aware that this temporary solution will no longer work with Python 3.0 (which may become the default in future versions of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Command Line:

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
$ pip install html5lib
```

Python 3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://www.example.com'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html5lib')
links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    print(link.string, link['href'])
```

Comment: @ Ryan Allen I am getting the malformed start tag message as well but I need to parse with an html file saved to disk, not an open url. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You would just open the file instead of using urlopen. `page = open('your/file/path/')`

Answer (score -2):

Look at column 3 of line 100 in the "data" that is mentioned in File "/usr/bin/Sipie/Sipie/Factory.py", line 298

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm having a hard time finding these data...  Still searching.  Still unfamiliar how all these programs work together...  Any additional hints?